# Unexpected token name «_000», expected punc «,» when building react native iOS

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm getting a `Unexpected token name «_000», expected punc «,»` but my file looks valid? Any ideas what this could be

**app/services/api/api.ts**

```
import { ApisauceInstance, create } from "apisauce"

// Use this import if you want to use "env.js" file
// const { API_URL } = require("../../config/env")
// Or just specify it directly like this:
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/app" // update later

export class Api {
  apisauce: ApisauceInstance

  setup() {
    this.apisauce = create({
      baseURL: API_URL,
      timeout: 10_000,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/vnd.api+json",
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
      },
    })
  }
}
```

```
error app/services/api/api.ts: Unexpected token name «_000», expected punc «,» in file app/services/api/api.ts at 27:21.
Error: Unexpected token name «_000», expected punc «,» in file app/services/api/api.ts at 27:21
    at minifyCode (/Users/cvdv/ss/mobile/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:99:13)
    at transformJS (/Users/cvdv/ss/mobile/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:317:28)
    at transformJSWithBabel (/Users/cvdv/ss/mobile/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:408:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/cvdv/ss/mobile/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:569:12)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

replace `timeout: 10_000,` with `timeout: 10000,`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remove the numeric separator, upgrade to [`metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.74.1`](https://github.com/facebook/metro/releases/tag/v0.74.1), or install  `@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator` separately and add to your `.babelrc` `plugins`.